NumPy ndarray non contiguous memory layout
I need some help in understanding the equations involved in finding the index of an element in an ndarray. I have been reading the Book "Guide to NumPy" by Travis A Oliphant. Link to the Book - Guide To Numpy
On page number number 28 of the book, Travis has given some equations, which, If I am understanding correctly is a formula to calculate index of an element(of an array stored on a storage medium) in a multidimensional array in both C-style and Fortran-Style. I am not able to get my head around that formula. The example that he has given is also not making much of a sense. I am pasting the image of that formula below, but if its not too much to ask you can even go to that link of his book and scroll to the page 28.
Any help in understanding it would be highly appreciated. enter image description here
I tried to do research on the available sources online and also tried to understand the meaning behind the mathematical notations used in the equation, but the description is not very clear. Besides there is not much help available on these equations anywhere.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Let's see if I can illustrate the example with numpy code.  I should add that in numpy the default order is C, and usually a numpy user doesn't need to know all the details.
Make a 1d array of 120 elements - continuous.
In [192]: x = np.arange(4*5*6)
In [193]: x
Out[193]: 
array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
        13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,
        26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,
        39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,
        52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,
        65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,
        78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,
        91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103,
       104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116,
       117, 118, 119])

And make 2 views, one with default C order, the other F:
In [194]: xc = x.reshape(4,5,6); xf = x.reshape(4,5,6,order='F')

For now I'll show the full 3d layout, but may, later, compress them.  Note how the sequential numbers, 0,1,2,... are layed out - by rows and columns:
In [195]: xc
Out[195]: 
array([[[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
        [  6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11],
        [ 12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17],
        [ 18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23],
        [ 24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29]],

       [[ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35],
        [ 36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41],
        [ 42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47],
        [ 48,  49,  50,  51,  52,  53],
        [ 54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59]],

       [[ 60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65],
        [ 66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71],
        [ 72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77],
        [ 78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83],
        [ 84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89]],

       [[ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95],
        [ 96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101],
        [102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107],
        [108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113],
        [114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]]])

3d F order:
In [196]: xf
Out[196]: 
array([[[  0,  20,  40,  60,  80, 100],
        [  4,  24,  44,  64,  84, 104],
        [  8,  28,  48,  68,  88, 108],
        [ 12,  32,  52,  72,  92, 112],
        [ 16,  36,  56,  76,  96, 116]],

       [[  1,  21,  41,  61,  81, 101],
        [  5,  25,  45,  65,  85, 105],
        [  9,  29,  49,  69,  89, 109],
        [ 13,  33,  53,  73,  93, 113],
        [ 17,  37,  57,  77,  97, 117]],

       [[  2,  22,  42,  62,  82, 102],
        [  6,  26,  46,  66,  86, 106],
        [ 10,  30,  50,  70,  90, 110],
        [ 14,  34,  54,  74,  94, 114],
        [ 18,  38,  58,  78,  98, 118]],

       [[  3,  23,  43,  63,  83, 103],
        [  7,  27,  47,  67,  87, 107],
        [ 11,  31,  51,  71,  91, 111],
        [ 15,  35,  55,  75,  95, 115],
        [ 19,  39,  59,  79,  99, 119]]])

Do the (1,3,2) indexing:
In [197]: xc[1,3,2]
Out[197]: 50
In [198]: xf[1,3,2]
Out[198]: 53

There's a function that does the same conversion from 3d index to 1d index.  (and there's a matching unravel...):
In [199]: np.ravel_multi_index((1,3,2),(4,5,6))
Out[199]: 50    
In [200]: np.ravel_multi_index((1,3,2),(4,5,6),order='F')
Out[200]: 53

See if you can find 50/53 in the above 3d arrays - block '1', row '3', column '2'.
Each array has, besides the shape, a strides attribute.  This is what actuallly implments the order.  These arrays are 'int4', 4 bytes per element.  So divide by 4 to get the (5*6,6,1) from the book:
In [201]: xc.strides
Out[201]: (120, 24, 4)        
In [204]: (1*120 + 3*24 + 2*4)/4
Out[204]: 50.0

Similarly for the 'F' case:
In [205]: xf.strides
Out[205]: (4, 16, 80)    
In [206]: (1*4 + 3*16 + 2*80)/4
Out[206]: 53.0

So your linked page just describes in math form, the calculation that goes on, under the covers, when we use an index like xc/f[1,3,2].
With 3d (and higher) arrays, 'C' and 'F' aren't the only layout options.  We could apply a transpose to xc:
In [208]: xx = xc.transpose(0,2,1); xx.strides
Out[208]: (120, 4, 24)

In [209]: xx[1,3,2]
Out[209]: 45
In [210]: xx[1]
Out[210]: 
array([[30, 36, 42, 48, 54],
       [31, 37, 43, 49, 55],
       [32, 38, 44, 50, 56],
       [33, 39, 45, 51, 57],     # row 3
       [34, 40, 46, 52, 58],
       [35, 41, 47, 53, 59]])

Usually with 'pure' numpy calculations we don't have to worry about order and strides.  The shape/strides parameters take care of all those messy details. But sometimes arrays get passed on to other compiled code, code which may expect certain layouts.  If that code was written in 'c/c++' it may expect 'C' order arrays.  If doens in Fortran, it may expect the other.
